# How can I get the field number that contains a MAC address with sed or awk?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, field

I'm trying to get the field number that contains a certain pattern (in this case a MAC address). Imagine we have something like this:

```
AAA BBB CCC xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx EEE FFF GGG
```

Where xx:xx... is a MAC address, so x's are alphanumeric.

If I use that line as the input, I want to obtain the number of the field where the MAC address is. In this case, "4".

I was thinking of sed or awk, but don´t know how to output the field number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Loop Over Fields With NF

Use a for-loop to check each field against a regular expression, using the POSIX character class for hexadecimal digits. When a match is found, print the matching field number.

```
echo 'AAA BBB CCC 00:00:00:00:00:00 EEE FFF GGG' |
    awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
               if ($i ~ /^([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]$/)
                   print i
                   next
         }'
4
```

Comment: Worked perfect! I thought of something like that, but thought that maybe there was a direct way, thanks!

Comment: Why the need for the loop though?

Comment: Is there a faster way to find the field number?

Comment: @Ghost If you just have one mac address per line then do `print i; next`. This stops the iteration right after it finds the match.

Comment: @jaypal You're right; it doesn't seem to make much difference on the provided corpus, but I added anchors and a next statement to limit backtracking and to fail faster on fields without matches. This *might* make a difference on much larger input files, but it takes the same 6ms either way on my system with the data provided.

Answer (score 1):

sed would work:

```
echo YOUR_STRING | sed -n 's/.*\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2\}\(:[a-zA-Z0-9]\{2\}\)\{5\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Example:

```
echo abc ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab abc | sed -n 's/.*\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2\}\(:[a-zA-Z0-9]\{2\}\)\{5\}\).*/\1/p'

ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab
```

Comment: Which sed are you using? This does *not* work with GNU sed as currently posted.

Comment: @CodeGnome i forgot to escape the `{` and `}`. `echo abc ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab abc | sed -n 's/.*\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2\}\(:[a-zA-Z0-9]\{2\}\)\{5\}\).*/\1/p'` outputs `ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab`.