# Obtaining the field that contains a value or string on Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Case example:

```
$ cat data.txt
foo,bar,moo
```

I can obtain the field data by using `cut`, assuming `,` as separator, but only if I know which **position** it has. Example to obtain value `bar` (second field):

```
$ cat data.txt | cut -d "," -f 2
bar
```

How can I obtain that same `bar` (or number field == `2`) if I only know it contains a `a` letter?
Something like:

```
$ cat data.txt | reversecut -d "," --string "a"
[results could be both "2" or "bar"]
```

In other words: how can I **know what is the field containing a substring** in a text-delimited file using linux shell commands/tools?

Of course, programming is allowed, but do I really need looping and conditional structures? Isn't there a command that solves this?

Case of specific shell, I would prefer Bash solutions.

> A close solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197894/how-can-i-get-the-field-number-that-contains-a-mac-address-with-sed-or-awk), but not exactly the same.

More same-example based scenario (upon requestion):

- For a search pattern of `m` or `mo`, the results could be both `3` or `moo`.
- For a search pattern of `f` or `fo`, the results could be both `1` or `foo`.

Comment: What about `grep -o '[^,]*a[^,]*' data`?

Comment: It seems to be working, I would say, @PesaThe : Clean, understandable, short and fast. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Following simple `awk` may also help you in same.

```
awk -F, '$2~/a/{print $2}' data.txt
```

Output will be `bar` in this case.

***Explanation:*** 
`-F,`: Setting field separator for lines as comma`,` to identify the fields easily.
`$2~/a/`: checking condition here if 2nd field is having letter a in it, if yes then printing that 2nd field.

---

***EDIT:*** Adding solution as per OP's comment and edited question too now.
Let's say following Input_file is there

```
cat data.txt
foo,bar,moo
mo,too,far
foo,test,test1
fo,test2,test3
```

Then following is the code for same:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /fo/){print $i}}}'  data.txt
foo
foo
fo
```

*OR*

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /mo/){print $i}}}' data.txt
moo
mo
```

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, could you please provide more feasible examples and add all conditions to your question, will try to provide code as per that then.

Comment: No more conditions to add. The "know what is the field containing a substring in a text-delimited file" is the only I can think of. Anyway, added more examples to the original question.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, please check my edited code once and let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Seems to be working now. Thanks you, RavinderSingh. Some comments about the meaning of the `NF` token could be useful for many users.